# Copying int64 Column to a New Column and Appending Str to end of each record in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 11 columns in a DataFrame, and want to clone the first column to a new column to be the 12th column, to be named mail.  The new mail column should contain all the column1 records and also add `str('@myexampledomain.com')` to it. The Column I want to copy to create the new column is the `"sAMAccountName"` column.  This is from my `output.csv` file

```
df.dtypes
Out[45]: 
sAMAccountName         int64
createHomeFolder      object
description           object
homeDrive             object
mustChangePassword    object
password              object
sn                    object
givenName             object
GradeLevel            object
Schoolcode            object
cn                    object
dtype: object
```

An example of a record from `sAMAccountName` currently is 15127.  The new column records should be `"15127@myexampledomain.com"`

I am on `python 3.6.3` and have read documentation everywhere and tried many different ways to do this but always get errors.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv',)
df_mail = df[df['sAMAccountName'] == 'mail'].copy()

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

I was hoping to get the new column titled `"mail"` with all the same rows as the `"sAMAccountName"` column.  Later on, I can figure out how to append the rest of the email address to the records. But right now, I can't get that new column created.

Comment: This is not a general interest question.  You are asking us to do your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to `copy` the `"sAMAccountName"` column and call it `"mail"`. Your current code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('output.csv',)
df_mail = df[df['sAMAccountName'] == 'mail'].copy()

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Returns a `TypeError` because you are trying to use boolean masking to filter out results, but as your `df.dtypes` says, `sAMAccountName` contains `int64` elements. To create a new column that copies another, do the following:

```
df['mail'] = df.sAMAccountName.copy()
```

This will add a new column (`mail`) to your existing dataframe.

To then convert all the elements to a `str` and add `"@myexampledomain.com"` to it, cast the `mail` column as a `str` using `.astype(str)`, concatenate, and save over itself:

```
df['mail'] = df.mail.astype(str) + "@myexampledomain.com"
```

Comment: Thank you Ian, that is exactly what I was looking for.  I voted it up arrow but don't have enough score yet so it doesn't yet show up.

Comment: @MikeColeman you could also select it as the correct answer. That should give you a couple reputation points.